# ubuntu server taking up 24gb is normal?

Tags: server, disk-usage

I installed ubuntu server x86 12.*

then I used the command supplied at the [community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI) to install xubuntu's GUI (cuz I'm a newb)

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Then installed:

- Xampp (Lampp variant)
- ruby
- nodejs

Among other tiny applications, and no data what so ever

now when I do a size check using `discus` it shows me that I'm using up 24gb of my 25gb partition.

This can't be normal is it?
What tools do I have to investigate further?

Thank's for all your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

24GB is excessive - my setup is relatively the same and occupies 7GB.

Open the Disk Usage Analyzer and have it scan your root volume `/` It will show the directories on the volume and how much space is being used for them. That might lead you to what is consuming so much space.

Comment: Wicked, that's exactly what I want, but I don't know what the tool is called/what command to use

Comment: It literally is Disk Usage Analyzer and should be in the standard apps installed with Desktop available through the Dash.